# How to read TCGA annotation format for nuclei segmentation dataset?

Tags: python, xml, image-segmentation

I'm interested in this nuclei segmentation dataset: https://nucleisegmentationbenchmark.weebly.com/

However the format is in TCGA.xml files, like this:

```
<Annotations MicronsPerPixel="0.252000">
    <Annotation Id="1" Name="" ReadOnly="0" NameReadOnly="0" LineColorReadOnly="0" Incremental="0" Type="4" LineColor="65280" Visible="1" Selected="1" MarkupImagePath="" MacroName="">
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute Name="Description" Id="0" Value=""/>
        </Attributes>
        <Regions>
            <RegionAttributeHeaders>
                <AttributeHeader Id="9999" Name="Region" ColumnWidth="-1"/>
                <AttributeHeader Id="9997" Name="Length" ColumnWidth="-1"/>
                <AttributeHeader Id="9996" Name="Area" ColumnWidth="-1"/>
                <AttributeHeader Id="9998" Name="Text" ColumnWidth="-1"/>
                <AttributeHeader Id="1" Name="Description" ColumnWidth="-1"/>
            </RegionAttributeHeaders>
            <Region Id="2" Type="0" Zoom="5" Selected="0" ImageLocation="" ImageFocus="0" Length="126.0" Area="1049.3" LengthMicrons="31.8" AreaMicrons="66.6" Text="" NegativeROA="0" InputRegionId="0" Analyze="1" DisplayId="2">
                <Attributes/>
                <Vertices>
                    <Vertex X="96.400000" Y="70.800000"/>
                    <Vertex X="96.600000" Y="71"/>
                    <Vertex X="96.600000" Y="71.400000"/>
                    <Vertex X="96.400000" Y="71.800000"/>
                    <Vertex X="96.200000" Y="72"/>
                    <Vertex X="96" Y="72"/>
                    <Vertex X="95.800000" Y="72.200000"/>
                    <Vertex X="95.600000" Y="72.400000"/>
                    <Vertex X="95.400000" Y="72.600000"/>
                    <Vertex X="95" Y="72.800000"/>
                    <Vertex X
```

I don't really understand how to read this so that it would convert into an image mask which I can then input into my library. Please help me, thank you very much.

Update: Annotation file: [file](https://github.com/dangmanhtruong1995/8051/files/5249977/TCGA-21-5784-01Z-00-DX1.zip)

I want to extract from it the mask for each pixel so that I can know each pixel belongs to which class.

Comment: Please narrow this down to a specific reproducible problem. Have you written any code at all? What is it that you don't understand? What exactly the expected output?

Comment: @mzjn No I have not written any code because I do not understand the format of the annation files. My expected output is the annotation image masks.

Comment: I know some reading with XML but I don't understand this specific format. I can't find any tutorial online about it.

Comment: 1) Upload a valid xml 2) explain what data you need to extract from it.

Comment: @balderman I have uploaded a valid xml and explained what I need to extract from it.

Comment: 1) the xml in the question should be a valid one. 2) use the xml elements / attributes when you explain the data you need to extract.

Comment: can you refer to the library/format you want the data in?

Comment: @balderman 1) It is a valid xml file 2) I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: the xml that is part of the question (not the one you have uploaded) is not a valid one. About the data you are looking for: use the elements and attributes of the xml. example:  "I X and Y attributes of all Vertex elements"

Comment: @balderman That xml file has 10000 lines so I only uploaded several first lines. Can you explain further about the element part ? Do you have any tutorial that talks further about it ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: create a small snippet of the xml but make sure its a valid one . see https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-xml-elementtree?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=898687156&utm_adgroupid=48947256715&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034352&utm_targetid=aud-392016246653:dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1008006&gclid=CjwKCAjw2Jb7BRBHEiwAXTR4jSc3k6AQwBnbiQETjSTh2L6dCMRRdSGs-YOqmEhZope5tQHrkjZ7WhoC0SgQAvD_BwE